# Compiling error when using the hiplarb installer with cuda and atlas during R compilation

Tags: r, compilation, ubuntu-12.04, atlas

I'm trying to compile hiplarb using the HiPLARb Installer.  Running the following command:

```
./HiPLARb.Installer --prefix=/home/ubuntu/mylibs
--cuda-home=/usr/local/cuda-5.5 --with-atlas --with-rpatched 
--r-install-dir=/home/mylibs/R-patched
```

Everything compiled fine until it comes to compiling R.  It terminates at the following line:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -Wl,--export-dynamic-fopenmp -L/usr/local/lib -o R.bin Rmain.o -L../../lib -lR -lRblas
```

it returns the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `drot_'
/usr/local/lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `dtrsm_'
/usr/local/lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `dswap_'
/usr/local/lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `dcopy_'
/usr/local/lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `ddot_'
/usr/local/lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `dgemm_'
/usr/local/lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `dscal_'
/usr/local/lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
/usr/local/lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `dsyrk_'
/usr/local/lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `daxpy_'
/usr/local/lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `drotg_'
/usr/local/lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `zgemm_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm now stuck and not sure how I can compile R to work properly.  Please help.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be finding the libRblas.so library.  Can you manually locate it?

Comment: there is a copy of libRblas.so in both /usr/local/lib and ../../lib

Comment: hmm... I think I know what the problem is... the file under /usr/local/lib is significantly smaller in size.  I've copied over the other file and everything seems to continue.  I'll see if it compiles successfully.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep that fixes it! there seems to be a corrupted file in the folder...

Comment: Why not post an answer explaining what you did.  Then we can call this question answered.

Comment: so I tried again from scratch, it's doing the same thing.  This time i made sure the files were at the correct location, but it seems that when compiling R, libRblas.so is always created in mylibs/R-2.15.2/lib folder.  I'm wondering if i'm missing some libraries so that the shared library libRblas.so isn't created properly?